# What consequences can I get if I use more than one instance of Curator framework per ZooKeeper cluster?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

In the Apache Curator website, there is a note here
http://curator.apache.org/curator-framework/index.html

> IMPORTANT: CuratorFramework instances are fully thread-safe. You should share one CuratorFramework per ZooKeeper cluster in your application.

But, how is it bad to use more than one instance? What disadvantages would I get that way?

Answer (score 2):

It would be slower and consume unnecessary system resources for no discernible advantage or gain. Other than that, it's fine.